# Creating a HTML response using a string inside a service worker's fetch event

Tags: javascript, html, service-worker

I am messing around with service workers at the moment.  I am trying to get the 'fetch' event to return custom HTML instead of just plain text like below:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  console.log("Caught a fetch!");
  event.respondWith(new Response("I want to return HTML here"));
});
```

Is this possible with the respondWith function?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Anyone else looking to do this - here is the answer:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  console.log("Caught a fetch!");
  event.respondWith(
      new Response("<h1>Hello!</h1>", {
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}
      })
   )
});
```